# Call Web Service Method from R

Tags: r, web-services, soap, webservices-client

I am calling a WebService Method using R with `SSOAP` Package. 
I Created a SoapServer Object

```
s2<-SOAPServer("http://www.webservicex.net","http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote")
```

and called the method using .SOAP as

```
reply2<-.SOAP(server = s2,method = "GetQuote",action = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote")
```

It is giving error as

> "Could not resolve host: http"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution...

```
reply2<-.SOAP(server = s2,method = "GetQuote",action = I("http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote"))
```